# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Store"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema

I'm using the Wes Boss Node.js tutorial and have been encountering a number of issues with schema errors.

My database is currently running on mLab and MongoDB Compass.  It was fine yesterday when I left for work, and I had just added my first bit of data to the DB successfully.  This morning I go to continue where I left off, and everything is suddenly broken.

I've tried deleting the `node_modules` directory, running `npm cache clean`, and `npm install`.  I have tried changing the order of the dependencies.  I thought it might be that the connection just needed restarted, so I closed the connection, exited Compass, re-opened and re-connected to the DB.  I tried deleting the "sessions" table and re-connecting.  No such luck.

I've tried plugging the database's server address into my browser's URL bar and I receive a message indicating that the connection was successful.

Error:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Store". Use mongoose.model(name, schema) 
at MissingSchemaError (C:\Users\Misha\Desktop\dang-thats-delicious\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\missingSchema.js:20:11)
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers');

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(expressValidator());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.h = helpers;
  res.locals.flashes = req.flash();
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.currentPath = req.path;
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.login = promisify(req.login, req);
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);

app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(errorHandlers.developmentErrors);
}

app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);

module.exports = app;
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const storeController = require('../controllers/storeController');
const { catchErrors } = require('../handlers/errorHandlers');

router.get('/', storeController.homePage);
router.get('/add', storeController.addStore);
router.post('/add', catchErrors(storeController.createStore));

module.exports = router;
```

start.js:

```
require('./models/Store');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Store = mongoose.model('Store');

require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`${err.message}`);
});

require('./models/Store');

const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I solved my own problem.  My `storeController.js` file needed `require('../models/Store');` at the top, right below `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`

However, now I'm getting another error, and I believe it's related to removing my stored sessions from the DB:

`express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option at app.js:38:9`

Going to attempt to re-create the DB and see what happens.